# margin-bottom issue on safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Safari don't take the margin bottom on my full height section. Is anyone ever got this problem?

I made a quick fiddle -> https://jsfiddle.net/m34hr01s/

It works great on chrome and firefox but not safari :/

I'm using bootstrap and wordpress

```
<body>
  <header></header>
  <section></section>
  <footer></footer>
</body>


html,body{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  position:relative;
  margin:0;
}

header{
  width:100%;
  height:50px;
  background:#3D2D34;
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  z-index:3;
}

section{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background:#799C94;
  z-index:10;
  margin-bottom:100px;
}

footer{
  width:100%;
  height:100px;
  background:#E3E29F;
  position:fixed;
  left:0;
  bottom:0;
  z-index:-1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a percentage for `height` allows to specify a dimension relative to the parent container dimension, not relative to the free space inside the container.

[CSS2](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visudet.html#the-height-property)

> % Specifies a percentage height. The percentage is calculated with respect to the height of the generated box's containing block.

Said that, trying to use `100%` when a box is partially filled by other objects is wrong. If your really want to use your code, an acceptable solution would be

```
header {
    position: relative;
}

section {
    height: calc(100% - 100px - 50px);
}
```

But `calc` should be your last option, so I really encourage you to use `flex` as much as you can.

```
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column; /* We are stacking boxes in column. */
  justify-content: space-between; /* Content is spread across all the free space. */
}

header {
  flex: 0 0 50px; /* Exactly 50px. */
  background: #3D2D34;
}

section {
  flex: 1; /* All the free space is mine. */
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  background: #799C94;
}

footer {
  position: fixed;
  width:100%;
  height:100px;
  left:0;
  bottom:0;
  background: #E3E29F;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6rfszhaf/5/)

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer! It will be a great solution is if wanted to always see the footer. In my case I want to keep the footer fix on the bottom and reveal it when scrolling down. 

Also is flexbox working better with internet explorer now? I had some issues with it in the past.

Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. I updated the answer to use a fixed footer. About support on IE, modern IE (Edge) supports flex completely. if you use Modernizr or another feature detect mechanism, you can by default use flex box and fallback using `calc()` on old IE.